# React, TypeScript: How define the parameters of handler in a child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm adding TypeScript to my React todo app right now and I'm basically done.

The problem lies in the Todo component. There I give the two event handlers: handleStatus and handleTodo the value: todos[index] as a parameter. This causes me to run into the following error message:

```
ERROR in src/components/Todo.tsx:26:88
TS2345: Argument of type 'Todos' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>'.
  Type 'Todos' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 29 more.
    24 |                 {todos[index].describtion}
    25 |                 <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index]) }  />
  > 26 |                 <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleDeleteTodo(todos[index]) } />
       |                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    27 |             </div>
    28 |         </>
    29 |     );
```

How can I define the two handlers or their parameters correctly in TypeScript?

Here is my Code:

Parent Component

```
interface TodoTableProps {
    mockTodos: Array<Todos>
}


let currentTodos: Todos  [];  

export const TodoTable: FunctionComponent<TodoTableProps> = ({ mockTodos }): ReactElement => {
    //Data input
    if(mockTodos){
        currentTodos = mockTodos;
    }
   
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Array<Todos>>(currentTodos);   
    const [enterTodo, setEnterTodo] = useState<string>('');


    //Enter Todo handler
    const handleEnterTodo = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      setEnterTodo(event.currentTarget.value);
    };
  

    //Clear Todo handler
    const handleClearTodos = (): void => {
        const cleanedTodos: Array<Todos> = []
       

        todos.forEach((element: Todos, index: number) => {
            if(todos[index].done == false){

                cleanedTodos.push(todos[index]);
            }
        });
       
        setTodos(cleanedTodos);
        
    }
    

    //Create Todo handler
    const handleCreateTodo = (): void => {

        //create new Todo
        const newTodo = {
            //id: todos.length+1,
            id: v4(),
            describtion: enterTodo,
            done: false
        };
     
        setTodos((todos: Array<Todos>) => 
            [
                newTodo,
                ...todos
            ]
        );
        setEnterTodo('');
        
        
    };

    //Delete Todod handler
    const handleDeleteTodo = (event: Todos): void => {
        
        const newTodos = [...todos];
        newTodos.splice(todos.indexOf(event), 1);
        
        setTodos(newTodos);   
    }

    //Status handler
    const handleStatus = (event: Todos): void => {
        
        const newStatus = event.done == true ? false : true;
        const newTodos = [ ...todos];
       
        newTodos.forEach((element, index) => {
            if(newTodos[index].id == event.id){
                newTodos[index].done = newStatus;                
            }
        });
        
        setTodos(newTodos);
    }
  
  
    return(
            <>
                <InputBar 
                    enterTodo={ enterTodo } 
                    handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo } 
                    handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
                    handleClearTodos= { handleClearTodos }
                />
                
                <TodosDisplay 
                    todos={ todos } 
                    handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                    handleStatus={ handleStatus }
                /> 
            </>      
    );
}
```

There Between is The Component TodoDisplay which just map the Todos and give the functions to the next Component

Child Component:

```
interface TodoProps {
    
    todos: Array<Todos>
    handleDeleteTodo: MouseEventHandler,
    handleStatus: MouseEventHandler,
    index: number,
    className: string

}

export const Todo: FunctionComponent<TodoProps> = ({ todos, handleDeleteTodo, handleStatus, index, className }): ReactElement => {
    

    return(
        <> 
            <div className= { className } key={ todos[index].id.toString() }>
                {todos[index].describtion}
                <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index]) }  />
                <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleDeleteTodo(todos[index]) } />  
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I am sure that the error lies in the Todo component or the parameters that are given to the handler there.

Thank you for help

Comment: this might not be the core issue here, but you probably want to type your arrow notation onClick functions to take a parameter of type MouseEvent to satisfy the Typescript callback interface

Comment: ex: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => handleDeleteTodo(todos[index])

Answer (score 0):

Addition:

```
TodoDisplay Component

interface TodosDisplayProps {
    todos: Array<Todos>,
    handleDeleteTodo: any,
    handleStatus: any
}

export const TodosDisplay: FunctionComponent<TodosDisplayProps> = ({ todos, handleDeleteTodo, handleStatus }): ReactElement => {


    // just for develope///////
    const lineBreak = <hr></hr>
    ///////////////////////////
    
    
    return(
        <>
            {todos.map((element: Todos, index: number) => {
                
                if(todos[index].done == false){
                    return(
                        <Todo
                            key={ todos[index].id.toString() }  
                            todos={ todos } 
                            handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                            handleStatus={ handleStatus} 
                            index={ index } 
                            className= "openTodos" 
                        />  
                    );                  
                } 
            })
            }
            {lineBreak}
            {todos.map((element: Todos, index: number) => {
                
                if(todos[index].done == true){                    
                    return(
                        <Todo
                            key={ todos[index].id.toString() } 
                            todos={ todos } 
                            handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                            handleStatus={ handleStatus} 
                            index={ index } 
                            className= "doneTodos" 
                        />   
                    );                   
                }
                
            })
            } 
        </>
    );
}
```

Button Component

```
interface ButtonProps {
    lable: string,
    disabled: boolean,
    onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>    
}

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ lable, disabled, onClick}): ReactElement => {
    
    return(
        <button type='button' disabled= { disabled } onClick= { onClick }>
                {lable}
        </button>
    );
}
```